# What's the best way of encapsulating CUDA kernels?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to make a CUDA project getting the closest to an OO design as possible. In the moment, the solution that I found is by using a Struct to encapsulate the data and for each method that needs some GPU processing, the implementation of 3 functions are necessary:

1. The method that will be called by the object.
2. A **__*global*__** function that will call a **__*device*__** method of that struct.
3. A **__*device*__** method inside the struct.

I will give you an example. Lets say I need to implement a method to initialize a buffer inside a struct. It would looks like something like that:

```
struct Foo
{
   float *buffer;
   short2 buffer_resolution_;
   short2 block_size_;
   __device__ initBuffer()
   {
      int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
      int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
      int plain_index = (y * buffer_resolution.x) + x;
      if(plain_index < buffer_size)
         buffer[plain_index] = 0;
   }
   void init(const short2 &buffer_resolution, const short2 &block_size)
   {
       buffer_resolution_ = buffer_resolution;
       block_size_ = block_size;
       //EDIT1 - Added the cudaMalloc
       cudaMalloc((void **)&buffer_, buffer_resolution.x * buffer_resolution.y);
       dim3 threadsPerBlock(block_size.x, block_size.y);
       dim3 blocksPerGrid(buffer_resolution.x/threadsPerBlock.x, buffer_resolution.y/threadsPerBlock.y)
       initFooKernel<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(this);
   }
}

__global__ initFooKernel(Foo *foo)
{
   foo->initBuffer();
}
```

I need to do that because looks like that I cant declare a **__*global*__** inside the struct. I've learned this way by looking at some opensource projects, but looks a lot troublesome to implement THREE functions to implement every encapsulated GPU method. 
So, my question is: Is that the best/only approach possible? Is that even a VALID aproach?

EDIT1: I forgot to put the cudaMalloc to allocate the buffer before calling initFooKernel. Fixed it.

Comment: CUDA only supports internal linkage, so I am not sure what advantage you are expecting to get by using this sort of design.

Comment: Well, I want to be able to invoke Foo methods, even if they need to call any kernel, as standard C++.
In this case, I would be able to call Foo f; f.init(res, size); Besides that, I can use the struct attributes inside the __device__ methods.

Comment: I would love to see a complete working example based on the psuedocode you have posted, because I fail to see how it could possibly work.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. I'm starting my first project and having the help of anyone more experienced on the subject would save me a lot of trouble/time. 
One good example following a similar approach: http://svn.pointclouds.org/pcl/trunk/gpu/kinfu/src/cuda/estimate_combined.cu. Is that a similar approach or there are missing spots that I can't see?

Comment: The code you just linked to doesn't do anything like what the code you posted purports to do. Note the complete separation of device and host code in what you linked to, and the complete lack of it in what you posted. One is fine, the other is impossible/illegal.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this... Why a struct with init() instead of a class with a constructor?

Comment: Why not declare a regular C style wrapper function, and then get one of your functions in your class to call that?

Comment: Roger and Conbhui made some good points. I followed my approach just because I didn't had any experience programming in CUDA and was highly biased towards that direction by trying to learn following the code I've posted some links ago. My question looks so silly now that I think about it.... If any of you post a pseudo code following that approach I will accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the goal to make classes that use CUDA while they look like normal classes from the outside?

If so, to expand on what O'Conbhui was saying, you can just create C style calls for the CUDA functionality and then create a class that wraps those calls.

So, in a .cu file, you would put definitions for texture references, kernels, C style functions that call the kernels and C style functions that allocate and free GPU memory. In your example, this would include a function that calls a kernel that initializes GPU memory.

Then, in a corresponding .cpp file, you import a header with declarations for the functions in the .cu file and you define your class. In the constructor, you call the .cu function that allocates CUDA memory and sets up other CUDA resources, such as textures, including your own memory initialization function. In the destructor, you call the functions that free the CUDA resources. In your member functions, you call the functions that call kernels.